# Having an issue inserting scraped content (via cheerio) in Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, cheerio

Specifically, I am trying to (using a very simple app built by going through the Discover Meteor book) scrape posts from Hacker News and insert them into the Meteor Collection, having the "New Posts" page update with 20 or so new articles scraped from the hacker news front page.

I have a button on my header wired up to a Meteor.call event:

```
Template.header.events({
   'click .hnPull': function() {
       Meteor.call('getHnArticles');
   }
});
```

This then (successfully) calls a Meteor.methods function titled getHnArticles:

```
getHnArticles: function() {

    hn_result = Meteor.http.get('http://news.ycombinator.com');
    console.log(hn_result);
    $ = cheerio.load(hn_result.content);

    var result_set = [];

    $('span.comhead').each(function(i, element){ //for ever <span class='comhead'>, do the following
          var a = $(this).prev();
          var rank = a.parent().parent().text();
          var title = a.text();
          var url = a.attr('href');
          var subtext = a.parent().parent().next().children('.subtext').children();
          var points = $(subtext).eq(0).text();
          var username = $(subtext).eq(1).text();
          var comments = $(subtext).eq(2).text();
          //parsed metadata object
        var metadata = {
            rank: parseInt(rank),
            title: title,
            url: url,
            points: parseInt(points),
            username: username,
            comments: parseInt(comments)
        };
        result_set.push(metadata);
    });
    console.log(result_set);

    for (var i = 0; i<20; i++) {

        var hn_post = result_set[i];

        var postAttributes = {
            url: hn_post.url,
            title: hn_post.title,
            message: 'Scraped automatically from Hacker News'
        };

        var user = Meteor.user(),
        postWithSameLink = Posts.findOne({url: postAttributes.url});

        // ensure the user is logged in

        if (!user)
            throw new Meteor.Error(401, "You need to login to post new stories");

        // Make sure the post has a title.  it can't be blank
        if (!postAttributes.title)
            throw new Meteor.Error(422, 'Please fill in a headline');

        // Make sure this isn't a duplicate post or repost
        if (postAttributes.url && postWithSameLink) {
            throw new Meteor.Error(302, 
                'This link has already been posted', 
                postWithSameLink._id);
        }

        // pick out the whitelisted keys
        // This keeps a nefarious client from monkeying around with our db
        var post = _.extend(_.pick(postAttributes, 'url', 'title', 'message'), {
            userId: user._id,
            author: user.username,
            submitted: new Date().getTime(),
            commentsCount: 0, 
            upvoters: [],
            votes: 0
        });

        Posts.insert(post);

    }


},
```

The end result of this is that the very, top ranked post from Hacker News gets inserted beautifully.  But then none of the others.

I am sending the array called result_set to console.log, and it outputs the front page:

```
I202504-11:50:57.551(-5)? [ { rank: 1,
I202504-11:50:57.551(-5)?     title: 'Is iOS7 jailbroken yet?',
I202504-11:50:57.551(-5)?     url: 'https://isios7jailbrokenyet.com/',
I202504-11:50:57.551(-5)?     points: 37,
I202504-11:50:57.552(-5)?     username: 'sethbannon',
I202504-11:50:57.552(-5)?     comments: 12 },
I202504-11:50:57.552(-5)?   { rank: 2,
I202504-11:50:57.552(-5)?     title: 'Valve joins the Linux Foundation',
I202504-11:50:57.552(-5)?     url: 'http://thenextweb.com/insider/2013/12/04/valve-joins-    linux-foundation-prepares-linux-powered-steam-os-steam-machines/',
I202504-11:50:57.553(-5)?     points: 276,
I202504-11:50:57.553(-5)?     username: 'kwestro',
I202504-11:50:57.554(-5)?     comments: 117 },
I202504-11:50:57.554(-5)?   { rank: 3,
I202504-11:50:57.555(-5)?     title: 'Google Acquires Seven Robot Companies, Wants Big Role in Robotics',
I202504-11:50:57.555(-5)?     url:  'http://spectrum.ieee.org/automaton/robotics/industrial-robots/google-acquisition-seven-  robotics-companies#.Up9CGN-hd98.hackernews',
I202504-11:50:57.555(-5)?     points: 71,
I202504-11:50:57.555(-5)?     username: 'eguizzo',
I202504-11:50:57.555(-5)?     comments: 29 },
I202504-11:50:57.556(-5)?   { rank: 4,
I202504-11:50:57.556(-5)?     title: 'Evading Airport Security',
I202504-11:50:57.556(-5)?     url: 'https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2013/12/evading_airport.html',
I202504-11:50:57.556(-5)?     points: 87,
```

And so on.  I get a nice large array.

Any idea on what's going wrong here?  Am I inserting the records too quickly as the code loops through for Meteor Collections, or is it a Mongo insert issue?

Thanks!  I'm pretty new to Meteor, and I love it.  But I'm still trying to wrap my head around using asynchronous node stuff within Meteor.

Edit: I forgot to add that when I query the MongoDB instance, it is showing that only the top link is inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Doh!!  I figured out what was going wrong!  I needed to use a continue statement instead of shooting out an error when I did THIS code:

```
if (postAttributes.url && postWithSameLink) {
        throw new Meteor.Error(302, 
            'This link has already been posted', 
            postWithSameLink._id);
    }
```